# Search Facebook Check-ins at given place

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-checkins

Is it possible to search and get user checkins or friend's checkins for a given place(lat/lon)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use FQL and the location_post table to find this.

```
SELECT id, page_id FROM location_post WHERE distance(latitude, longitude, '37.86564', '-122.25061') < 10000
```

...should show user and friend checkins near the lat/lon.

See the [location_post Docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/location_post/)

Comment: Can you provide any links for the usage of this API with examples or demos